# Powershell get nuget credentials from Nuget.Config

Tags: powershell, nuget

Powershell 7. I am trying to set up private PS repository. I need to provide credentials for it and I do not want to have them hardcoded in script. For that I've got Nuget.config file which lists feeds and credentials for them (creds are actually environment variables if that matters).

Is there a way to force Powershell to use credentials from NugetConfig when registering PSRepository?